# Binary file issues/random access

Tags: c++

I need help with a function that displays records that were stored in a binary file using character arrays.  Every other part of the code works as intended.  The display function, which is the 5th item on the menu, needs reworking.  The data needs to be stored in a binary file and be accessed in random access mode.

P.S I'm not sure how to even set up the function to grab the salaries of each department, and accumulate them into a report. I'm still very new to C++.

```cpp
// Need to concatenate salary’s from all employees on binary files of each department and display it as a report using the displayreport() function.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_DEPT = 3, MAX_EMPLOYEE = 7;
const int ID_SIZE = 20, NAME_SIZE = 50;

typedef struct Department
{
    //department structure
    char depID[ID_SIZE];
    char depName[NAME_SIZE];
    char depHeadName[NAME_SIZE];
    char depTotalSalary[];
} D;

typedef struct Employee
{
    //employee structure
    char employeeID[ID_SIZE];
    char employeeName[NAME_SIZE];
    double employeeSalary;
    int employeeAge;
    char employeeDepID[ID_SIZE];
} E;

void openFileDep(fstream &f)
{
    //Function to open file departments.dat
    f.open("departments.dat", ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary);

    if(f.fail())
    {
        //If file failed to open
        f.open("departments.dat", ios::out|ios::in | ios::binary| ios::trunc);
        if(f.fail())
        {
          //If file failed to open
           cout << "Error opening file....";
           exit(0);
        }
        else
          return;
    }
    else
        return;
}

void openFileEmp(fstream & z)
{
    //Function to open file employees.dat
    z.open("employees.dat", ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary);

    if(z.fail())
    {
        //If file failed to open
        z.open("employees.dat", ios::out|ios::in | ios::binary| ios::trunc);

        if(z.fail())
        {
            //If file failed to open
            cout << "Error opening file....";
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    else
        return;
}

void add_newdep(fstream & f)
{
    //Function to add new record to file
    D dep;

    f.clear();//To clear the state back to good
    f.seekp(0,ios::end);//To move file pointer to end to append

    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"Enter the NEW Department Data:";
    cout<<"\nDept ID: ";

    cin.getline(dep.depID, ID_SIZE);

    cout<<"Dept Name: ";

    cin.getline(dep.depName, NAME_SIZE);

    cout<<"Head of Dept Name: ";

    cin.getline(dep.depHeadName, NAME_SIZE);

    cout<<"\n";

    f.write((char *)&dep, sizeof(dep));//Write content of structure department to file
}

void add_newemp(fstream & z)
{
    //Function to add new record to file
    E emp;

    z.clear();//To clear the state back to good
    z.seekp(0,ios::end);//To move file pointer to end to append

    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"Enter the NEW Employee Data:";

    cout<<"\nEmployee ID: ";

    cin.getline(emp.employeeID, ID_SIZE);

    cout<<"Employee Name: ";

    cin.getline(emp.employeeName, NAME_SIZE);

    cout<<"Employee Salary: $";

    cin>>emp.employeeSalary;

    cin.ignore();                     //?

    cout<<"Employee Age: ";

    cin>>emp.employeeAge;

    cout<<"Department ID: ";

    cin>>emp.employeeDepID;

    cout<<"\n";

    z.write((char *)&emp, sizeof(emp));//Write content of struct employee to file
}

void displaymodifyDep(fstream & f)
{
    //Function to display selected record and modify option
    D dep;

    f.clear();//To clear the state back to good
    f.seekg(0,ios::beg);//To move file pointer to beginning

    fstream o("temp.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);//Used to store modified records

    int n = 0;

    while(f.read((char *)&dep, sizeof(dep)))//Read whole file for number of records
        n++;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        //File is empty
        cout<<"\nNo record found. File empty";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //File is not empty
        cout<<"Which record to EDIT:";
        cout<<"\nPlease choose one of the following... 1 to "<<n<<" : ";

        cin>>n;//Now n is used to store record number to display

        f.clear();//To clear the state back to good
        f.seekg(0,ios::beg);//To move file pointer to beginning

        int i = 0;

        while(f.read((char *)&dep, sizeof(dep)))
        {
            //Read each record and check if i == n
            i++;

            if(i == n)
            {
                //If i == n then print that record and return
                cout<<"\nDisplay Department Details: ";
                cout<<"\nDept ID     : "<<dep.depID;                     // need to SET SPACES
                cout<<"\nDept Name   : "<<dep.depName;
                cout<<"\nDept Head   : "<<dep.depHeadName<<endl;

                cin.ignore();

                cout<<"\nEDIT the Department Data:"<<endl;
                cout<<"Dept Name: ";

                cin.getline(dep.depName, NAME_SIZE);

                cout<<"Head of Dept Name: ";

                cin.getline(dep.depHeadName, NAME_SIZE);

                cout<<"\n";

            }o.write((char *)&dep, sizeof(dep));//Write to temp.dat
        }

    }//Close both files

    f.close();
    o.close();

    remove("departments.dat");//Remove inventory.data
    rename("temp.dat", "departments.dat");//temp.data contain modified record and now has been renamed to departments.dat
}

void displaymodifyEmp(fstream & z)
{
    //Function to display selected record and modify option
    E emp;

    z.clear();//To clear the state back to good
    z.seekg(0,ios::beg);//To move file pointer to beginning

    fstream o("temp.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);//Used to store modified records

    int n = 0;

    while(z.read((char *)&emp, sizeof(emp)))//Read whole file for number of records
        n++;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        //File is empty
        cout<<"\nNo record found. File empty";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //File is not empty
        cout<<"Which record to EDIT:";
        cout<<"\nPlease choose one of the following... 1 to "<<n<<" : ";
        cin>>n;//Now n is used to store record number to display

        z.clear();//To clear the state back to good
        z.seekg(0,ios::beg);//To move file pointer to beginning

        int i = 0;

        while(z.read((char *)&emp, sizeof(emp)))
        {
            //Read each record and check if i == n
            i++;
            if(i == n)
           {
                //If i == n then print that record and return
                cout<<"\nDisplay Employee Details: ";
                cout<<"\nID     : "<<emp.employeeID;                     // need to SET SPACES
                cout<<"\nName   : "<<emp.employeeName;
                cout<<"\nSalary : "<<emp.employeeSalary;
                cout<<"\nAge    : "<<emp.employeeAge;
                cout<<"\nDept   : "<<emp.employeeDepID<<endl;

                cin.ignore();

                cout<<"\nEDIT the Employee Data:"<<endl;
                cout<<"Employee Name: ";

                cin.getline(emp.employeeName, NAME_SIZE);

                cout<<"Employee Salary: $";

                cin>>emp.employeeSalary;

                cin.ignore();                     //?

                cout<<"Employee Age: ";

                cin>>emp.employeeAge;

                cout<<"Department ID: ";

                cin>>emp.employeeDepID;

            }o.write((char *)&emp, sizeof(emp));//Write to temp.dat
        }
    }//Close both files

    z.close();
    o.close();

    remove("employees.dat");//Remove inventory.data
    rename("temp.dat", "employees.dat");//temp.data contain modified record and now has been renamed to employees.dat
}

//#5 THIS FUNCTION NEEDS REWORKING

void displayreport(fstream & f, fstream & z)
{
    fstream depdepName("departments.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
    fstream empemployeeSalary("employees.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);

    D dep;
    E emp;
    double totaldepsalary = 0;

    f.clear();
    z.clear();

     cout << "\nSalary Report By Department \n";
     cout << "\n";
     cout << "Dept         :" << dep.depName << endl;
     cout << "Total Salary : $" <<emp.employeeSalary << endl;
     cout<<"\nSalary Report By Department \n";
}

//main starts here!
int main()
{
    //Driver function
    fstream f, z;

    openFileDep(f);//Function to open file
    openFileEmp(z);

    int option;

    do
    {
        cout<<"Human Resources Menu";
        cout<<"\n1. Create Department";
        cout<<"\n2. Create Employee";
        cout<<"\n3. Edit Department";
        cout<<"\n4. Edit Employee";
        cout<<"\n5. Display Salary Report";
        cout<<"\n6. -- Quit --";
        cout<<"\nPlease make a selection : ";

        cin>>option;

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: add_newdep(f);break;
            case 2: add_newemp(z);break;
            case 3://display records && Modify file records
            displaymodifyDep(f);
            //close file
            f.close();
            openFileDep(f);//Open file again
            break;
            case 4://display records && Modify file records
            displaymodifyEmp(z);
            //close file
            f.close();
            openFileEmp(z);//Open file again
            break;
            case 5: displayreport(f, z);
            case 6: break;
            default: cout<<"Please enter a valid choice (1 - 6): ";
            cin>>option;
        }
    }while(option != 6);
    cout<<"Thank you, goodbye.";

    f.close();
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and explain what the problem is.

Comment: It seems your functions needs **implementing**, not reworking, since there is no code to even try and read anything. Did you try at all to implement it on your own?

Comment: Do you need the binary files to be in little or big endian format? Does it matter for you?

Comment: Single letter variable names quickly turn into a debugging nightmare. Single letter type names will have the same effect, but probably get there faster.

Comment: @Lev M I'm not sure how to even set up the function to grab the salaries of each department and accumulate them into a report, i'm still very new to c++

Comment: Since this is C++ steer towards using `std::string` and stay far, far away from fixed-length C-style character buffers. This gets rid of a lot of code necessary to ensure you don't overflow those buffers.

Comment: @tadman if the task is to read already existing binary files, it won't be possible to get away from fixed size character buffers.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why would you say that? If you write an `operator<<` and `operator>>` you can read and write from whatever format is necessary, including fixed-length fields. Dumping a raw `struct` into a file, like this code does, is asking for huge problems.

Comment: @tadman if you're proposing overriding `operator<<` and `operator>>` for `std::string`, you'll end up creating way more problems that you solve.  Maybe I went too far by saying "won't be possible", but it will still be easier with fixed buffers.  You can easily copy those to/from `std::string` if you want.

Comment: @MarkRansom I mean for these particular `struct` definitions, that's all, not `std::string` itself.

Comment: This is some seriously C-flavoured C++ code, like the `typedef` is not necessary, in C++ the `struct` part can be omitted automatically. You can also add functions to things like `Department` directly so you can do things like `Department::load()` and `Department::save()`, keeping things better organized.

Comment: @tadman it's likely that the binary file layout is based on the struct layout, so changing the struct will cause lots of pain.  E.g. the file was written with `fwrite(&dept, sizeof(dept), 1, f);`